# Implement own method with multiple parameters in PowerShell

Tags: object, powershell

I want do create a custom object with a method that takes more than one parameter. I already managed to add a method that takes one parameter, and it seems to work:

```
function createMyObject () {
    $instance = @{}

    add-member -in $instance scriptmethod Foo {
        param( [string]$bar = "default" )
        echo "in Foo( $bar )"    
    }
    $instance
}
$myObject = createMyObject
```

But every time I try to add a method with takes two parameters by simply adding another `[string]$secondParam` - clause to the param-section of the method, the invocation

```
$myObject.twoParamMethod( "firstParam", "secondParam" )
```

does not work. The error message in my language says something like "it is not possible to apply an index to a NULL-array".

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't immediately clear to me what you're trying to do with this, but it reminds me of a [similar question that I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18705545/775544) in the past. Perhaps give it a look if you are interested in a similar implementation.

Comment: I'm trying to define methods with more than one parameters...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this seems to work (at least in PowerShell v4)...

```
add-member -in $instance scriptmethod Baz {
    param( [string]$bar = "default", [string]$qux = "auto" )
    echo "in Baz( $bar, $qux )"
}
```

To call it, I did:

```
[PS] skip-matches> $myObject.Baz("Junk","Stuff")
in Baz( Junk, Stuff )

[PS] skip-matches> $myObject.Baz()
in Baz( default, auto )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "somethink like this"? This is exactly the code I was trying. Can you show how you call the method on the instance then?

Comment: @Sh4pe, I updated my answer w/ how I tested my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a version of this that I got working.

```
function Demo ([ref]$var) {
    $var.Value = 5
    $var
    }

[psobject] $changeMe = New-Object psobject
$changeMe = 0
$changeMe # Prints 0
$v = Demo([ref]$changeMe)
$changeMe # Prints 0, should print 5
```

To assigned a value to an object, you need to use the Value property of the reference object.  Also, I instantiate an object instance and pass a reference to that.